# Quartz Scheduler obtain information when Job starts/stops

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am writing functionality using the Java Quartz library, and this is my first time trying it. I need to find a way to know when a specific Job or Trigger starts and when it stops.  So far, I have been able to get the Job set up (which currently just prints something to console), and the Trigger set up based on the schedule input by the user (using a Cron expression for the same). I tried to use a Job/trigger listener implementation to find out when the job/trigger executes/stops but it looks like it fires every minute. (as it is supposed to).

Example:
The app expects the user to enter calendar times/dates for doing X. Let's say from 3/3/18 to 3/18/2018, where I want the Job to run between 21:00:00 and 21:30:00 on Saturdays. The cron expression would be `0-0 0-30 21-21 ? * SAT *`. What I need is to know when the job starts executing and when it stops so I can send "events" to notify the user that his "schedule" has begun/stopped. Using the `triggerFired` or the `jobWasExecuted` methods provide me the execution of the `Job`...which is every second. So, that the console output  from the `triggerFired` method happens only at the 21:00s and the console output from `triggerComplete` happens only at the 21:30s? As in the following times:

- Job/trigger start at 3/3/2018 21:00:00
- Job/trigger stop at 3/3/2018 21:30:00
- Job/trigger start at 3/10/2018 21:00:00
- Job/trigger stop at 3/10/2018 21:30:00
- Job/trigger start at 3/17/2018 21:00:00
- Job/trigger stop at 3/17/2018 21:30:00

Is there a way to obtain that information? Thanks for your help.

Comment: With CRON second being `0-0`, why would it fire every second? Wouldn't it only fire once per minute, when the second value is `0`?

Comment: Why wouldn't the logging consider `3/3/2018 21:01:00` to be a start time? It is the first start in the second interval of `0-0` for minute `1` and hour `21`. You need to clarify your rules of when you'd want a log record to be created, because there are many fringe cases of CRON expressions where the little you've said makes no sense. Then, when you've defined the rules, you need to write the code to suppress the log records for all the `triggerFired` that you don't want to see.

Comment: @Andreas: To your first question: No, the CRON format for Quartz takes it in this format: `second-second minute-minute hour-hour day(month) month day(week)`. I used https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html to verify before adding logic that converts human language to CRON format. It fires every second.

Comment: To your second question, do you mean I need to "log to console" only on the first firing instance, and suppress the remaining (apart from the last firing time)? Seems quite a convoluted way to do it...shouldn't Quartz provide another way?

Comment: The website you linked says *"Every second between :00 and :00"*. There is only one second in a minute with a second-value of `00`, so in effect that means "every minute at the beginning of the minute". Your trigger doesn't fire "every second". `0-0` is really the same as `0`, and website says *"At second :00, every minute between :00 and :30"* for that. Try clicking the `NEXT EXECUTE DATES` on the website and see for yourself. **Fires once per minute**. --- And remember, the ranges are inclusive, so the trigger fires **31 times** in the 9 PM hour.

Comment: *"Shouldn't Quartz provide another way?"* No, why should Quartz do that? The trigger fires a total of 31 times in a week. There is no specific intervals where it fires. When would you want `0,15,30/10 * 6,12,17-21/2 ? * SAT *` to log, and why? And why would Quartz agree with your why for not logging *all* the trigger run times, if it had any such capability?

Comment: Ah, you are correct. So, how do I solve the original problem? How do I send an "event" (or just log to console to be simple in this case) when the job/trigger first fires and when it stops?

Comment: Read my [second comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49090776/quartz-scheduler-obtain-information-when-job-starts-stops?noredirect=1#comment85187910_49090776) again.